# Image alt tag aren't display in post when inspect the sources code in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

You will be clear if you see the image below. I insert alt tag in all image of WordPress Media Library but when I use those images of my post and inspect to see the alt text, no alt tag display here.

[image]

[image]

**When I open those image in a new tab the I see image url in alt tag.**

[image]

I am using "Auto Image Attributes From Filename With Bulk Updater" plugin for Auto Attributes but After Deactivate I get the same result. Can anyone help me to fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible your browser has cached the page so it does not update with the alt text. Have you tried reloading with no cache? Does your site have a cache plugin?

Answer (score 0):

this is Arun the author of "Auto Image Attributes From Filename With Bulk Updater" plugin.

So WordPress stores image attributes in two locations, one in the media library and one is embedded into the post HTML. Updating the one in media library does not automatically update the one in post HTML. I have written in more detail here: https://imageattributespro.com/how-wordpress-store-image-attributes/

Since the changes you made only reflected in the media library, that could be the reason why it's not reflected in the front end.